# Why it's this react implementation not working?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and i'm trying to create an element like this:

```
function helloWorld(){
  return(
    <h1>Hola mundo</h1>
  )
}

function Card() {
  return (
    <div className="card"> Your message is: <helloWorld/> </div>
  );
}
```

The result of this it's the Card component rendering but without the helloWorld content.
Why is this not working and What it's the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Component name should start with a Capital letter. 
read here [https://blog.pusher.com/troubleshoot-react-errors/#:~:text=All%20React%20component%20names%20must,letter%20compiles%20down%20to%20React](https://blog.pusher.com/troubleshoot-react-errors/#:%7E:text=All%20React%20component%20names%20must,letter%20compiles%20down%20to%20React).

Try below code:

```
function HelloWorld(){
  return(
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  )
}

function Card() {
  return (
    <div className="card"> Your message is: <HelloWorld /> </div>
  );
}
```